# Led works fine but Relay not working by bc547

Tags: power-electronics

I want to drive a 5v relay with bc547. I am using 1k resistor at base but relay is not working. I replaced relay with a led but it is working fine. Resistance of relay coil is 70ohms. Please help. A rough diagram is shown.[image]

Comment: How did you verify the output current?  Using the same voltage , I choose Rb =10xRcoil.

Comment: Excellent example of how easy it is to write a good question without necessarily writing a lot of text.

Comment: You haven't got a clamp diode (flyback diode) connected across your relay coil. The resulting high voltage on relay switch-off will destroy the transistor. You'll find loads about this on the Internet.

Comment: Does your relay work when powered directly with the 5v supply? As suggested above you may have burned the transistor.  Add a protection diode on the relay coil

Comment: Also double check the transistor pinout. TO-92s are famous for offering the same transistor in several mutually incompatible pinouts (is that a BC547 or a BC547L?)

Comment: Irelay = V/R = 5/70 ~= 70 mA.  Ib BC547 ~+ V/R = (5-0.6)/ 1k ~= 4.5 mA.  Required Beta = 70/4.5 =~ 15 so ample available from transistor. [**BC547 datasheet**](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/BC/BC546.pdf) - pinout = OK looking from bottom flat up = CBE. BUT Transistor is good for 100 mA max = VERY marginal here. VCEsat <= 600 mV with 1C = 100ma and 5 mA drive. TRansistor may be on low side of spec. What is Vce when on? Try 470 R base resistor. Best use BC337-400 as jellybean transistor - MUCH more capable and often as cheap.

Comment: [**BC337 datasheet**](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/BC/BC337.pdf) - BC337-40 is highest beta version.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't got a clamp diode (flyback diode) connected across your relay coil.

The resulting high voltage on relay switch-off will destroy the transistor.

You'll find plenty of details on this on the Internet.

Answer (score 1):

If we assume that you have forgotten to draw the flyback diode in the diagram but have employed it in the practical design, and still the relay doesn't operate, then the only reason for this could be an inadequate current from the 5V source.

Remember as voltage rating for relays become lower, current demand become higher, a 5V relay may require significantly high current to operate compared to a 12V relay.